# Letting an image expand into view using an animation

Tags: android, android-animation

In my Android app, I have a `TextView` with a white background. When it is clicked, its background will change to a `.png` picture of some icon by calling `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon)` on the `TextView`. This works as intended, but the change is rather abrupt. I would like to make the icon appear more gradually; when the `TextView` is clicked, a tiny version of the icon should appear in the center of the `TextView` and then immediately expand and fill out the entire `TextView`. I believe the best way to do this would be by using an animation, which of the available animation types in Android are best for this task?

In case it is not clear what I mean, I drew a sketch to illustrate. The second sequence shows how the code works right now, the first shows how I would like it to be.

[image]

Comment: Do you have all those intermediate drawable resources?

Comment: @joao2fast4u Well I could generate them, but that sounds like an ineffective way to do it. I imagined that it was possible to do this with a single image which is repeatedly resized. Does no such type of animation exist?

Comment: @joao2fast4u And in case my question wasn't clear: I didn't mean for this to happen necessarily in five different stages as my diagram suggest, but rather as a continuous process that happens so fast that the eye perceives it as an animation.

Comment: Why don't you use an ImageView instead? Because with setBackgroundResource() you cannot control the position or dimension of your resource. It will always fit the entire TextView background.

Comment: @joao2fast4u Thank you for your suggestion, but I am using a TextView because I need it for the logic of my app; the View must sometimes show text. This does not have to matter though, since I can always superimpose an ImageView at the same location with the same width and height as the TextView in the background. So if you do happen to have a solution that would work for an ImageView, do tell, it's all the same to me!

Comment: Do you want your animation to repeat on every click or is it just a one shot animation?

Comment: @joao2fast4u Either way would work for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I managed to get the effect you want with an `ImageView`, using `ScaleAnimation`. Here's what you have to do:

First, our XML `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/scale_anim"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

It has fixed dimensions and a white background.

The animation will start with one click with this, inside your `onCreate()` method:

```
ImageView starImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.scale_anim);

    starImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ScaleAnimation starScaleAnimation =
                    new ScaleAnimation(0.3f, 1f, 0.3f, 1f,
                            ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                            ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

            starScaleAnimation.setDuration(500);
            ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
            ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = starScaleAnimation;
            v.startAnimation(scaleAnim);
        }
    });
```

We are applying a scale animation on the `ImageView` that stars with 30% of the original size and scales to 100% of its size, from its center point. The duration of this animation is half a second. All these parameters can be changed.

Every time you click the `ImageView`, your drawable will be applied and the animation will start.

Comment: Thank you! I am accepting this answer since this does exactly what I needed. I'd like to ask you in case you know: I notice that the first time I click on the View, the icon will not expand very smoothly on the screen, but on all subsequent clicks it will expand very smooth and nice. Do you know if I can improve it so that it will also expand in a natural fashion on the first click? (No worries if you don't know because then I'll just ask a second question on SO at some later time).

Answer (score 2):

Try this way if it solve yours.

- Create an ImageView (X) above your original ImageView (A) - same size and same place as (A)
- Animate (X) with `ObjectAnimator`, listen for the `onAnimationEnd` call and set the (A)'s background. Then remove (X).

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I like the idea, but I don't understand what `ObjectAnimator` does exactly since I don't find a tutorial. Does it scale/resize the `ImageView` in question? If so, am I supposed to call the `ofFloat` method?

Comment: You can do a lot of animations using ObjectAnimator. For the backward compatible, use the NineOldAndroids lib. Check it and how to use at http://nineoldandroids.com/.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that it is not backward compatible now that I tried to implement it - it requires API level 11. Is there really no way I can do this without using NineOldAndroids? It was so simple when I wanted to implement translation animations, I am surprised that resizing is so much more complicated.

Comment: Today I had the chance to look into this more closely and I have some comments: I think using ScaleAnimation like suggested by joao2fast4u could be a good solution (for the backward-compatible). At least it worked for me. Also, it may not be necessary to create a second ImageView to superimpose on the TextView - I tried this at first as you suggested but I had problems with letting this look good; it is difficult to set the exact coordinates of a View since the setX and setY methods are not backwards-compatible. So I settled for just letting the animation work on the TextView itself. :)